# Steepest descent direction with surface constraint (geometry problem)

Tags: geometry, optimization

Let say I have a function $f(x,y,z)$, defined on a surface by the level curve $g(x,y,z)=c$. I want to know what is the direction of the steepest descent at a given point, taking into account the constraint. I don't use the Lagrange multiplier as I am not interested in minimizing the function.

So here is how I do : the steepest descent direction (without constraint) is given by the gradient $\vec d=\frac{\vec\nabla f}{\|\vec\nabla f\|} $. Now I want to project this vector onto the constraint surface. The normal vector to the constraint surface is $\vec n = \frac{\vec\nabla g}{\|\vec\nabla g\|} $.

I think that if I project $\vec d$ onto $\vec n$, then subtracting the result to $\vec d$, I will have my constraint steepest descent direction $\vec d_{constrained}$.

$\vec d_{constrained}= \vec d - ( \vec d . \vec n ) \vec n $

Looks good to you?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Looks great to me. For any direction vector $v$ the directional derivative is given by $df(v)=\nabla f\cdot v$, thus you want to find a tangent vector to your surface which maximizes this product. This is indeed what you did.